# Insert parent and child at once via Eloquent in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to insert a two related objects via `Eloquent` and I get an `Integrity constraint violation error` on one of the tables. Here is what I am trying:

The representation of the relationship:

```
class DataParticipant extends Model
{
    public function data_config()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\DataConfig');
    }
}

class DataConfig extends Model
{
    public function data_participant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\DataParticipant');
    }
}
```

Then, I am trying the following:

```
$dataParticipant = new DataParticipant();

$dataParticipant->ip = // ip
$dataParticipant->code = // code
$dataParticipant->study_name = // study


// Prepare the config child.

$dataConfig = new DataConfig();
$dataConfig->config = // config via json_encode 


// Store the child associated to the parent.

$dataParticipant->data_config()->save($dataConfig);
```

The error is on `data_participant_id` column, which belongs to the `DataConfig` model. My guess is that there is no `id` on which the two can be linked. I want to ask you:

- How can I accomplish this without having to first save the `DataParticipant` then retrieve it from the database and then store the `DataConfig` on the resulted `id`?

Comment: Have you tried to save `$dataParticipant` ? before creating $dataConfig please `$dataParticipant->save()` and if the problem still persist then try to get a fresh $dataParticipant before using that in last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First save the first model

```
$dataParticipant->save ();
```

Then save the second model

```
$dataParticipant->data_config()->save($dataConfig);
```

This won't retrieve the data from DB at all, and `$dataParticipant` id will be automatically set with the last insert id

Comment: Assume this action is performed by multiple users at the same time. Does it get the correct last inserted id? Or is there a way to tell the laravel to get the last inserted id by this user?